# creating objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between creating new object like in function ManA or by calling constructor ManB?

```
function ManA(name, age)
{
    return { name: name, age: age, getAge: function() { return this.age; } };
}

function ManB(name, age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.getAge = function() { return this.age; };
}

var manA = ManA("Tom", 28);
var manB = new ManB("Frank", 25);
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: Might want to disambiguate what you're looking for. After reading it a couple times and thinking hard, I'm guessing you're more after "are there performance improvements not using a constructor?". Also, bear in mind no proto-typical-inheritance with ManA.

Comment: @DawsonToth there is no prototypal inheritance in either, they are both equal except the second one returns real `ManB` objects while the first one returns plain objects and can be called without `new`

Comment: In this case, the only differences is that `manA instanceof ManA` returns `false` whereas `manB instanceof ManB` returns `true`.

Comment: I'm interested in any kind of diferences that I should be aware of when using any of these structures eg performance or the one that FelixKling mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the `manA` `[[Ptototype]]` chain is:

```
manA -> Object.prototype -> null
```

and the `manB` `[[Prototype]]` chain is:

```
manB -> ManB.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

so in the second case, you can add methods to `manB` (and all instances of `ManB`) by adding them to `ManB.prototype`. You can't do that with `ManA` instances [see note]. So the `getAge` method can be on the constructor's prototype, saving a few bytes of memory for each instance.

#### Note

You can add methods to the `manA` prototype chain, but the only one available is `Object.prototype`, so every object will inherit them. That is considered very bad style, you should leave built–in objects alone.